# Why is this buffer defined inside of a loop?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I've always been under the impression that I shouldn't define a variable inside of a loop because it's unnecessary or wasteful. This makes me wonder if the following recv() function needs a fresh buffer for each iteration of the loop:

```
while (totalBytesRecvd < echoStrLen)
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    numBytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
    ...
    totalBytesRecvd += numBytes;
    buffer[numBytes] = '\0';
    fputs(buffer, stdout);
}
```

The documentation for recv() doesn't mention anything about how it uses the buffer pointer. For a better understanding, I tried defining the buffer just before the loop, and recv() appears to overwrite the buffer, instead of redefining it. Which makes sense since recv() is passed a pointer to the beginning of the buffer.

Is there a specific reason to define a buffer over and over again inside of a loop? Or is my basic understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`recv`, as `read` and other similar functions, doesn't care about the previous content of the buffer, it uses it just to write the result.

Not that it would make a difference anyway: since you are not initializing your buffer, its content will be "undefined" even if you declare the variable as local to the loop.

Also, on most C implementations:

- not initializing that variable means that will take whatever happens to be on the stack at that location, which in turn means that it'll be taking the same location as it were at the previous iteration, effectively giving you the exact same result as having the variable outside the loop.
- stack allocations are cheap - in general they just require to adjust a register;
- actually, they are even cheaper: usually the register adjustment is done just at the beginning of the function, accounting for all the local variables; the scoping of a local variable becomes just a compile-time construct, since it's allocated when the function starts.

Obviously, instead, if you *initialized* your variable it would be different - the code to perform the initialization would have to run at each iteration; but, as said above, there's no need to initialize anything, `recv` just doesn't care about the current state of the buffer.

Comment: All very helpful (and similar) answer's so far. Can anyone point me to their source? Or can I find all of this in my compiler documentation? Compiler optimization was glossed over in the C Programming book I read.

Comment: My source is way too much time spent looking at assembler generated by compilers :).  In general, don't worry about this kind of optimisation.  Use the right algorithms for the right job, and only consider these kinds of tweaks if you can demonstrate a piece of code *needs* optimisation.

Comment: @src It's a very old mantra: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" --Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 5):

It is not wasteful. It declares the scope of this variable. The compiler may reclaim the space on the stack for other purposes not allocating more from the stack out of this scope. It requires no extra expenses at run time - the compiler calculates the necessary stack space at compile time and adjusts the stack pointer only once in the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Defining a variable in a loop is only bad if it's expensive to construct, and that's rarely the case in C.

With even the most basic of optimisation, it's not even going to bother modifying the stack pointer on each iteration of the loop.  Many compilers will zero-initialise an array in debug mode, but unless this buffer is huge, it's not likely to be a big issue.

In C++, you might think about not declaring a variable with an expensive constructor if you can get away with only constructing it once outside the loop, but that's not going to be an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable inside a loop just reserves stack space for it; it will not clear the contents or otherwise touch the variable. Thus, this style of declaration is no more expensive than declaring it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> I've always been under the impression that I shouldn't define a
>   variable inside of a loop because it's unnecessary or wasteful.

You're always been under an incorrect impression, and one that not only is baseless, but pits a very bad practice -- premature optimization -- against a very good one, declaring variables as close to their use as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I also used to think that moving declarations out of loops would result in faster code, especially for larger structures such as arrays.  I think this is often true with malloc'd (heap) data, because you can waste a lot on overhead by calling malloc and free within the loop.  For stack data (like yours) I don't think this as big of a problem.

However, I recently encountered the opposite situation, where I moved a declaration out of an inner loop and actually ended up with *slower* code. I came up with a few possible explanations for this:

1. When the declaration was moved to wider scope the compiler wasn't able to optimize the code as effectively.
2. A larger amount of data was being kept in memory between loop iterations, resulting in inefficient cache usage.

Anyway I don't have a good reference for this, but moving definitions in or out of loops can make the code faster or slower depending on the situation.  You have to measure the performance before and after changing the code to see if there is a difference.

Comment: 'I also used to think that moving declarations out of loops would result in faster code, especially for larger structures such as arrays.' -- *Why* did you think that? 'I think this is often true with malloc'd (heap) data' -- allocation isn't declaration! If you had a statement like `int foo = very_long_calculation(rand());` then of course it would be expensive to move the *calculation* inside a loop. How is a call to malloc any different?

Comment: Re *"actually ended up with slower code"*: Perhaps the CPU register allocation changed? Or even using a memory location instead of a register.